# GNU make - how to get complete command line used to invoke make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to get the complete command line used to invoke `make`?

I invoked my `make` using `--print-data-base` and I cannot find any `make` variable that contains the string `--print-data-base` nor its shorthand `-p`.

I **did** find, in the print database, the line

`-*-command-variables-*- := MAKEFILES=C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/ImpTarget.mk`

but nothing that shows the **complete** command-line used to invoke `make`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to print the original command line, but you can peek at each part of it with the following variables

```
$(error $(MAKE) $(MAKEFLAGS) $(MAKEOVERRIDES) $(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

Comment: Why is this wrapped in a `$(error ...)`? This always just makes `make` error. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Make-Control-Functions.html